# BigQuery: how to fold some rows with contextually same data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this table with the following schema:

```
id int,
state int,
ts timestamp
```

This table records state change in a device but there are some records which are recorded without the state change. Here is an example:

```
id:1, state:1, ts:2018-08-16 01:25:00
id:1, state:1, ts:2018-08-16 02:15:00
id:1, state:3, ts:2018-08-16 03:14:12
id:1, state:1, ts:2018-08-16 04:35:01
id:1, state:3, ts:2018-08-16 05:41:21
id:1, state:3, ts:2018-08-16 06:44:57
```

I want to collapse the first 2 rows only to use the first one and the last 2 rows to the first one of them like these:

```
id:1, state:1, ts:2018-08-16 01:25:00
id:1, state:3, ts:2018-08-16 03:14:12
id:1, state:1, ts:2018-08-16 04:35:01
id:1, state:3, ts:2018-08-16 05:41:21
```

In short, I want to collapse consecutive rows with the state in this chronological order with the first row in the group. How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(first) FROM (
  SELECT *,  
    state <> IFNULL(LAG(state) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts), state + 1) first
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE first
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question (I added few more rows to demonstrate difference from other two already given answers)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 state, TIMESTAMP('2018-08-16 01:25:00') ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, '2018-08-16 02:15:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, '2018-08-16 02:16:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, '2018-08-16 02:17:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, '2018-08-16 03:11:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, '2018-08-16 03:14:12' 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(first) FROM (
  SELECT *,  
    state <> IFNULL(LAG(state) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts), state + 1) first
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE first
-- ORDER BY id, ts
```

result will be

```
Row id  state   ts   
1   1   1       2018-08-16 01:25:00 UTC  
2   1   3       2018-08-16 02:16:00 UTC  
3   1   1       2018-08-16 02:17:00 UTC  
4   1   3       2018-08-16 03:11:00 UTC
```

Please note: the other two answers will give you below (which I really doubt is what you would expect)

```
Row id  state   ts   
1   1   1       2018-08-16 01:25:00 UTC  
2   1   3       2018-08-16 02:16:00 UTC
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was misleading. I updated my question with a better example. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried? my answer gives you exactly that! try and let me know :o)

Comment: sure, no problem as you can see from my answer  - it was not misleading to me even before your update  :o) I usually try to read in between the lines  - but definitely - thank you for update - so others have better understanding of your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use RANK() function for this purposes, e.g.

```
   #standardSql 
   SELECT id, state, ts 
    FROM (
     SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id, state ORDER BY ts ASC) rank 
     FROM %YOUR_TABLE_NAME%
     )
    WHERE rank=1
```

`PARTITION BY id, state` means that `id, state` are unique identifiers and `ORDER BY ts ASC` means that rank() function will order rows by timestamp (oldest - higher)

Comment: Sorry, my example was misleading. I updated my question with a better example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple group by should do it too?

```
SELECT id, state, min(ts) ts
FROM %YOUR_TABLE_NAME%
GROUP BY id, state
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was misleading. I updated my question with a better example. Thanks!